# Javascript function profiling

Tags: javascript

I'm currently testing Javascript Visualization Toolkits and want to measure execution time, memory consumption etc.

I know hot to profile Javascript with the chrome dev tools, google speed analyzer and so on, but I want users to perform the tests on their own and display the results. (without using dev tools or installing an extension)

Is there a library or something that can be used to achieve this? Subtracting start and end time for each function does not seem like a good solution.
Best case scenario would be a Library to profile individual functions.

Comment: Something like http://benchmarkjs.com? It's used by http://jsperf.com, works on most browsers including IE6, but doesn't profile memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: you will not be able to get CPU profile or memory usage using a JS-based testing solution. If this is what you are after, a Chrome extension may very well be the way forward.

If, however, this doesn't bother you, if you are after a ready-made solution, [**Benchmark.js**](http://benchmarkjs.com/) may prove to be a good starting point.

The method it uses is akin to what you mentioned - taking time differences in execution. However, it does so multiple times (100 or more times) in order to average out the statistical errors. This allows your results to be free of truly random errors (this does not, however, mean that your data will be meaningful.).